# RemoteFX in Windows 7

Tags: rdp, remote-desktop

Anyone know if Windows 7 SP1 RDP to Windows 7 SP1 will benefit from enabling RemoteFX?

(Not using HyperV at all.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word no.............its a server based technology.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff817578%28WS.10%29.aspx
http://blogs.technet.com/b/virtualization/archive/2010/03/17/explaining-microsoft-remotefx.aspx